# For a 3 dimensional dataset, What is the minimum number of points that are required to fit a hyperplane?

Tags: deep-learning

For a 3 dimensional dataset, What is the minimum number of points that are required to fit a hyperplane?

if i have n data points then do i require n+1 data points to fit in a hyperplane?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking that you have n data points then do you need n+1 data points to fit a hyperplane?  No, I think n data points are enough to fit the hyperplane you don't need one extra point in your data to be able to fit a hyperplane, moreover if u have n datapoints how can u have n+1 datapoints?

Answer (score 0):

stack overflow is a programming related problem exchange. I think [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is an appropriate platform for your question. Having said that, for any D dimensional dataset, where D is greater than 2, you require only 3 non-collinear points to define a hyperplane. Not more, not less. There is a special condition, in which a single point can also define hyperplane, case being, hyperplane should not be a subspace, then, there always exists a point lying in the hyperplane which is at least distance from the origin. This single point can solely define any hyperplane which is not a subspace (it is an affine subspace)